# ssh and environment variables remote and local

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to use a remote variable and a local variable in the same remote ssh command

```
export CASSANDRA_DIR=/opt/cassandra

ssh root@sdi-prod-02 <<\EOF
  export READ=$(grep IPADDR /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 |awk -F= '{print $2}')
  echo "listen_address: $READ" to directory "$CASSANDRA_DIR"
EOF
```

The $READ variable is working just fine while the CASSANDRA_DIR is not working.  The following does work for CASSANDRA_DIR

```
ssh root@sdi-prod-02 echo "directory=$CASSANDRA_DIR"
```

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Where is the `$CASSANDRA_DIR` variable defined?

Comment: I edited the post to add that.  It comes from this script(well, it actually is a bit more convoluted but for all intensive purposes is basically set in the local script not the remote one.  Also, I am actually using "clush" which runs the ssh command on many servers but the ssh doesn't work so the clush cmd won't work.

Comment: Minor nit: `grep ... | awk ...` can always be merged as:
`awk -F= '/IPADDR/'{print $2}' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What should be expanded locally, keep the sigil `$` as is, like `$foobar`

What you want to be expanded remotely, you may use backslashes : `\$foobar`

By default in *here-docs*, the variable are expanded.

Ex. :

```
cat<< EOF
$UID
EOF
```

To avoid expanding in *here-doc*, you can use this form :

```
cat<< 'EOF'
$variable_that_will_not_been_expanded
EOF
```

or yours :

```
cat<< \EOF
$variable_that_will_not_been_expanded
EOF
```

both works.

Comment: I added to my ssh script above the lines echo dir1=$CASSANDRA_DIR
echo dir2=\$CASSANDRA_DIR and neither printed the directory so this solution did not work.

Comment: thanks, that fixed me all up!!!!  wow, just removing that "\" before the EOF is what fixed my issue so I now have \$REMOTE_VAR and $ORIGINAL_HOST_VAR and both work, one reads local and one reads remote.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to use a here-doc you can do it this way:

```
export CASSANDRA_DIR=/opt/cassandra

ssh root@sdi-prod-02 "
   export READ=\$(grep IPADDR /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 |awk -F= \'{print \$2}\')
   echo \"listen_address: \$READ\" to directory \"$CASSANDRA_DIR\"
"
```

Comment: I am really trying to get it to work with the EOF such that the script is much easier to read as what is in the EOF can be 10 lines sometimes.  Is there no way to work with the EOF to use the local variables?

Comment: plus 1 on your post since it helped me combine your answer and sputnicks answer into my final result.

Comment: Glad I could help in some way :)

Answer (score 1):

My final result is thus which works great (notice I cahnge \EOF to EOF instead!!!!! and then escape the remote variables

```
export CASSANDRA_DIR=/opt/cassandra

ssh root@sdi-prod-02 <<EOF
  export READ=$(grep IPADDR /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 |awk -F= '{print $2}')
  echo "listen_address: \$READ to directory $CASSANDRA_DIR"
EOF
```

IT all works great in that READ is generated remotely and CASSANDRA_DIR is the var on my original machine.

Dean